# Using the template folder from another module in my django app

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to use the postman module that is used for user to user messages in django and I have installed the app and set up the urls for it but whenever I click the link I get this error. [image]

as far as I can tell the templates are there but django cant seem to find them. Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Here's some of my code that might help too,

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li><a href="{% url 'login.views.course' %}">MyCourse</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'login.views.timetable' %}">Timetable</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'login.views.logout_view' %}">logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="/messages">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

---

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'login/../login/../login/templates'), os.path.join('C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django-postman-3.3.1/postman/templates')]
    ,
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

---

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls', namespace="postman")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you post the directory structure of your app and your INSTALLED_APPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postman app comes with a `postman/base.html` template, which extends `base.html`. You are expected to create this `base.html` template, and include certain blocks in it.

See [the docs](http://django-postman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#templates)  for more info.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that the base.html that was included in the template folder was extending another base.html